# I don’t know how to explain, but something strange happened with the font in Eclipse ... (screenshots inside)

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, fonts

I have a macBook and I liked the font from IntelliJ IDEA called JetBrainsMono. Using the macOS OS "Fonts" utility, I installed this font. But I use Eclipse most often and therefore I decided to install such a font in Eclipse. I did this through "Eclipse" -> "Preferences" -> "Appearance" -> "Colors and Fonts" -> "Basic" -> "Text Font" -> "Edit". After that, familiar combinations of characters began to look different (don't give an attention to red highlighting):

[image: Beautiful but unfamiliar]

This is "-> <= !=  <=>" sequence, which was corrected automatically when I typed in. I know that in other text editor it will take a familiar look - in "Notepad" for example. But I want disable this feature in Eclipse. How can I do this?

Comment: These are ligatures which are part of the font. Use a different (monospace) font, e.g. [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro).

Answer (score 0):

As @howgler said, these are part of the font and this combinations of symbols looks this way in any application.